# Embed html in php code

Tags: php, html

I am not following the PHP OOP as of yet. I have one main plugin.php file, which contains the main class of my plugin. This is where, I enqueue javascript file (plugin folder/assets/plugin.js) , which contains the ajax request which will trigger once the button is pressed to run the PHP file (plugin folder/run-script.php) which will call the python script (plugin folder/assets/python.py) . All custom API endpoints are mentioned in (plugin folder/includes/wp-admin-api.php)

I want to know where should I embed the code given below, in my plugin :

a WordPress hook you could use to add content to the post edit page, near the ‘publish’ button:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_submitbox_misc_actions/#user-contributed-notes

I followed some of the links below, but they did not work.

[https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-php-in-html-code–cms-34378](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-php-in-html-code%E2%80%93cms-34378)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140270/how-to-write-html-code-inside-php-i-want-write-html-code-within-the-php-sc